# How can I run commands of a python script from OS process sampler jmeter?

Tags: python, testing, jmeter

I have main.py which runs certain functions... and I want to test in jmeter. I've been told that OS process sampler can do it but I don't have any idea on how to do it...

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you have `main.py` file with the following code:

```
import sys


def hello():
    print('Hello, ' + sys.argv[1])


hello()
```

You can run it using JMeter's [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) as follows

[image]

the output can be observed using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener:

[image]

More information: [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter)

Comment: What do I put in the Command section?